# Bitrix24 API : How to update a CRM Deal file custom field

Tags: bitrix

we are using Bitrix24 cloud version and created a custom field at CRM Deals.

How can I update this custom field (type:file) using Bitrix API?

Already tried :

```
$fileContent = file_get_contents(dirname(__FILE__)."/images/MM35_PG189a.jpg");

$batch = array(
  'deal_update' => 'crm.deal.update?'
    .http_build_query(array(
      'id' => 2,
      'fields' => array(
        'UF_CRM_1516125473' => array(
          'filedata' => array(
            'file.jpg',
            base64_encode($fileContent)
          )
        )
      )
    ))
);

$data = call($_SESSION["query_data"]["domain"], "batch", array(
  "auth" => $_SESSION["query_data"]["access_token"],
  "cmd" => $batch,
));
```

Comment: did you ever manage to get this solved?

Answer (score 1):

Error in variable name: filedata -> fileData

Comment: It is hard to see the helpfulness of this answer. To improve that, use a little more prose. Also explaining why the very small difference in spelling is relevant would help a lot, including with the helpfulness for future/other readers.

Answer (score 0):

@Ivan answer is exact, you simply have a typo in `fileData` attribute name.

Your code looks very similar to example in Bitrix documentation for [crm.deal.update](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/rest_help/crm/cdeals/crm_deal_update.php) (example only on russian page version):

To update your custom field with type:file using Bitrix API, you should run sample code below. It will upload 100x100 px black square in PNG format.

```js
BX24.callMethod("crm.deal.update", {
  id: 3,
  fields: {
    UF_CRM_1516125473: {
      fileData: [
        "black-square-100x100.png",
        "iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAGQAAABkAQAAAABYmaj5AAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAABNJREFUeNpjGAWjYBSMglFAVwAABXgAAUmp06QAAAAASUVORK5CYII=",
      ],
    },
  },
  params: { REGISTER_SONET_EVENT: "N" },
});
```

There is also some notes on [File Processing](https://training.bitrix24.com/rest_help/js_library/rest/files.php) in documentation.